# Every time writes new file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, file

I am working on a c# console application. I am saving some data into a text file. Every time the programs are run it saves the data into that file without overwriting into it. Now I want to save the data into a new file every time I send a request/runs the new program.

```
var result = XmlDecode(soapResult);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(result);

XmlReader read = doc.CreateReader();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(read);
read.Close();

if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables["Reply"] != null && ds.Tables["Reply"].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    string refNo = string.Empty;
    string uniqueKey = string.Empty;
    string meterNo = string.Empty;
    List<string> ls = new List<string>();
    if (ds.Tables["Reply"].Rows[0][0].ToString().ToUpper() == "OK")
    {

        if (ds.Tables["Names"] != null && ds.Tables["Names"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            uniqueKey = ds.Tables["Names"].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
        }

        if (ds.Tables["NameType"] != null && ds.Tables["NameType"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            refNo = ds.Tables["NameType"].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
        }

        if (ds.Tables["Meter"] != null && ds.Tables["Meter"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (ds.Tables["Meter"].Columns.Contains("mRID"))
            {
                meterNo = ds.Tables["Meter"].Rows[0]["mRID"].ToString();
                processedRec++;
            }


        }
    }
    log = uniqueKey + " | " + refNo + " | " + meterNo + " | " + Environment.NewLine;
    ls.Add(log);
}
File.AppendAllText(filePath, log);
```

How can I create a new file every time?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Change the value of `filePath`.

Comment: so delete the file if it exists and save the file?#

Comment: @BugFinder no I don't want to delete the file

Comment: You havent said anything other than you want a new file.. how would we know

Comment: Use `File.CreateText` instead of `File.AppendAllText`

Comment: @LeoBartkus: `File.CreateText` Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. **If the target file already exists, it is overwritten**

Comment: @sujithkarivelil Yes, that is literally the question he asked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom file name every time and make use of [`File.WriteAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2) (which will Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.) instead for `File.AppendAllText`

In your case the `filePath` should be dynamic which can be construct like this:

```
string basePath = ""; // this should be path to your directory in which you wanted to create the output files
string extension = ".xml";
string fileName = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}","MyFile",DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy_hhmmss"),extension ); 
string filePath = Path.Combine(basePath,fileName);
```

In the above snippet the `DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy_hhmmss")` will be the current time(at the time of execution of the code) which will be differ in each execution so the file name will differ in each run. And at some later points you can search/group files based on these common pattern.

One more thing:

In your code you have used a variable `List<string> ls` which is populated with all logs, and you are writing the the contents of `log` to the file, which contains only the last record. So the statement for writing the content should be:

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, String.Join("\n",log));
```

or even simply

```
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, log);
```

Comment: I tried your code and done the following `File.WriteAllText(filePath, log);`. The log is created with a date-time stamp but it includes only the last record.

Comment: @Faisal: Yes ofcource `log` will having only the last value, you have populated the values to a  list called `ls`, use that instead for `log` which will contains all the logs

Comment: previously while using `File.AppendAllText` all the logs were in the file not the latest one

Comment: How you iterate the rows of table or nodes of xml?

Answer (score 0):

Make a unique filePath. Something like this:

```
var filePath =$"{folderPath}\txtFile_{Guid.NewGuid()}";
```

This will make the file to be always unique. The guid can be replaced with something more meaningful like Unix Timestamp as well.

Answer (score 0):

simply make your filePath unique, for example by using Ticks

```
var filePath = $"app-log-{DateTime.Now.Ticks:X}.log";
```